# Нужно ли брать слово "свой" в кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация

... боясь проехать "свою" остановку...  ... зашел в "свой" (гостиничный) номер.

Answer (score 2):

В этих примерах - не нужно: это общепринятое обозначение притяжательности по отношению к *человеку*; понятно, почему *своей* называют остановку, на которой всегда выходят или просто намереваются выйти, и вполне обычно отличать *свой* гостиничный номер (= в котором живут) от *чужого* (в который напр. зашли по ошибке).